# Jquery page switcher

Tags: jquery, css, load, refresh, switchers

I have a problem with this code
when I click on the next page>>>a page  refresh two times.<<<
Its possible to stop? sorry for my poor english

**Code**

`jQuery(document).ready(function() {`

```
$(".container").css("display", "none");

$(".container").fadeIn(1000);

$("a.pager").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    linkLocation = this.href;
    jQuery(".container").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);       
});

function redirectPage() {
    window.location = linkLocation;
}});
```

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop propagation of the click event (which is different from `.preventDefault()`):

```
$("a.pager").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  linkLocation = this.href;
  jQuery(".container").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);
  return false; // stop propagation of the click event 
});
```